# vue js component doesn't rerender on the same page

Tags: vue.js

I have a component

```
<template>somecode</template>
<script>
 export default {
        name: 'Card',
        created() {
                axios.get(apiObjUrl)
                      somecode
                })
     }
</script>
```

this my url:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/card/12

But I have a problem:

when I use router-link like this:

```
<router-link to="/card/155"> card 155</router-link>
```

my url changes: http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/card/155

but the `created()` method doesn't get fired.
so I don't make new xhr request to api 
and data not changes
what do I do?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna https://jsfiddle.net/rowrt1x1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just because your component is already created. You may try using the lifecycle hook `updated()` instead of `created()`.

```
 export default {
   name: 'Card',
   updated() {
     axios.get(apiObjUrl)
     somecode
   })
 }
```

*Note: This will only work if your DOM changes. If you just want to listen on url changes and update accordingly you better `$watch` your route like this.*

```
export default {
  name: 'Card',
  created() {
    axios.get(apiObjUrl)
    somecode
  }),
    watch: {
    '$route': function() {
        // do your stuff here
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I change `created` method to `updated` updated method doesn't get fired the first time I load the page(I don't know why) nothing in console

Comment: I don't really got it

Comment: I need to call   the same code  `axios.get(apiObjUrl)` on page created when I refresh the page, and on url change with `router-link`, so how do I exactly do it?

Comment: I've edited my code, there was a little mistake. Leave your current code as it is and add the `watch` property to it. This can take in any property you want and listen on changes. Whenever a change happens (in this case whenever your url changes) it'll just fire up any expressions within its execution block. More here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative you can setup a  [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) attribute on your `<router-view>` like this:

```
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

As `<router-view>` is a component itself and unique keys force replacement of component instead of reusing it. So you can make use of life cycle hooks.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/Lop7caa1/3/)

Comment: whta exactly `:key` attr does here?

Comment: @user2950593`key` tells Vue’s virtual DOM algorithm to identify VNodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list. In simple words it tells vue that the node should be replaced (rerendered) with a new one as new key is passed with a new route path on every route change.