# How to change the content of webpage when I change the path of dynamic vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, reload

I am using vue-router to write a dynamic router .and when I jump from one path to another, I find the path is indeed changed but the web page does not reload and I have no idea why.

- the router definition is as follows:

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: '/lecture/:lecture_name',
        name: 'Lecture',
        component: LecturesBase,
    }
]
```

- and the dynamic web page vue components is like this:
- LectureBase.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <a-layout>
            <LectureNavigation />
            <LectureTemplate
                :page_name="page_name"
            />
            <!-- <router-view>
            </router-view> -->
            <tui-juhe />
        </a-layout>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import { ref } from 'vue';
import router from "@/router/index";
import { onBeforeRouteUpdate, useRoute } from "vue-router";

import LectureNavigation from "@/views/lecture/LectureNavigation.vue";
import LectureTemplate from "@/views/lecture/LectureTemplate.vue";
import TuiJuhe from "@/components/advertisement/TuiJuhe.vue";

export default {
    name: "LectureBase",

    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();
    },

    components: {
        LectureNavigation,
        TuiJuhe,
        LectureTemplate,
    },

    // props: {
    //     page_name: String, // 中文标题
    // },

    data() {
        return {
            $router: router,
            page_name: ref(this.$route.params.lecture_name),
        }

    },
    watch: {
        '$route' (to, from) {
            console.log('# to url: ' + to.path);
            console.log('# to url: ' + this.$route.params.lecture_name);

            this.page_name = this.$route.params.lecture_name;
            console.log('# to url: ' + this.page_name);
            this.$forceUpdate();

        }
    },

    // methods: {
    //     refresh() {
    //         d
    //     }
    // },

    created() {
        console.log("# url： " + this.$route.params.lecture_name);
    }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

- LectureTemplate.vue

```html
<template>
    <a-layout class="variable_content" style="padding: 0 24px 24px">
        <a-breadcrumb style="margin: 16px 0" :routes="router">
            <a-breadcrumb-item>
                <router-link to="/">
                    <home-outlined />
                </router-link>
            </a-breadcrumb-item>
            <a-breadcrumb-item>
                <router-link to="/lecture/lecture_home_page">
                    NLP 教程
                </router-link>
            </a-breadcrumb-item>
            <!--a-breadcrumb-item> Home </a-breadcrumb-item-->
            <a-breadcrumb-item>{{ this.title }}</a-breadcrumb-item>
        </a-breadcrumb>
        <a-layout-content :style="{
          background: '#fff',
          padding: '24px',
          margin: 0,
          width: '100%',
          minHeight: '280px',
        }">
            <div>
                <h1><b class="b_green">{{ this.title }}</b></h1>
                <p class="description_text">
                    发布日期：{{ this.established_time }}&emsp;阅读量：{{ this.frontend_page_count }}
                </p>

                <div v-html="markdownToHtml"></div>
            </div>
        </a-layout-content>
    </a-layout>
</template>

<script>

import { useMeta } from 'vue-meta';
import router from "../../router/index";
import { stat_instance } from "@/utils/request";
import blog_asset from "@/utils/blog_request";
import {
    HomeOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons-vue";

export default {
    name: 'LectureTemplate',

    components: {
        HomeOutlined,
    },
    // setup() {
    //     useMeta({ title: this.title})
    // },

    props: {
        page_name: String,  // 英文名，用于请求后端，展示 url
    },

    data() {
        return {
            router: router,
            title: '',
            established_time: '',
            frontend_page_count: 0,
            markdown: "### loading ...",
        }
    },

    computed: {
        markdownToHtml() {
            var markdown_content = this.md(this.markdown);
            return markdown_content;
        }
    },

    created() {
        console.log("## temp url: " + this.page_name);
        stat_instance({
            url: "/stat_api/frontend_page_statistics",
            data: {
                page_name: this.page_name,
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.frontend_page_count = response.data.frontend_page_count;
                this.title = response.data.title;
                this.established_time = response.data.established_time;
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.frontend_page_count = 0;
            });

        blog_asset({
            url: "/lecture/" + this.page_name + "/README.md",
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.markdown = response.data;
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.markdown = "### Failed to request markdown file.";
            });

    }

}
</script>

<style lang="less" scoped>
h1 {
    width: 100%;
    // height: 80px;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.b_green {
    color: #00B441;
}

.description_text {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #777777;
}
</style>
```

So, what is wrong with my code, and the complete project code is at [JioNLP_online](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/JioNLP_online).

You could git clone this repository and execute `npm run serve` to try this code and check the bug.

The program indeed captured the dynamic path of the vue-router but the web page does not changed at all.

Comment: does anyone could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution I found

I found this post about the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372518/vue-js-component-doesnt-rerender-on-the-same-page).

Basically you need to add the `:key` attribute to the `<vue-router>` component where your page is rendered.

Example:

```js
// this re-renders the page when the path changes
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

### My solution

The `:key` solution didn't work for me, because I didn't want the router to re-render. This would cause my smooth transition animation between the routes to break. So I tried solving it in a different way.

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted, watchEffect, ref } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const isLoading = ref<boolean>(true);
const route = useRoute();

const loadData = async (id) => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  // load dynamic data here and change ref values
  isLoading.value = false; // after load
};

watchEffect(() => {
  loadData(route.params.id);
});

onMounted(() => {
  loadData(route.params.id);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your recommending page. just changing `created` method to `updated`  can smoothly get what I want.